# Multiple buttons CSS issue

Tags: html, css

So I have a YouTube API that pulls a playlist... If the results are more than 15, it breaks 16-30 into page , 31-45 into page three, etc and has 'next page' 'previous page' buttons for navigating.

Take a look: http://d.pr/i/QbZw

When I add the CSS to get it to match the rest of the page, the buttons over lap: http://d.pr/i/BpIc

Here's the HTML:

```
  <div class="button-container back_image">
  <img src="Pictures/Footer.jpg" width="1060" height="75">
  <button id="prev-button" class="paging-button" onclick="previousPage();">Previous Page</button>
  <button id="next-button" class="paging-button" onclick="nextPage();">Next Page</button>
  </div>
```

Related CSS:

```
.back_image{
    width: 1060px;
    height:auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    }   
.paging-button {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    color:#fff;
    height:25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    width: 1060px;
    color: white;
    }
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution...  Based on some of the comments you guys made...  I made each button an individual ID

```
  </div>
  <!--Footer-->
  <div class="button-container footer_back_image">
  <button id="prev-button" class="paging-button btn" onclick="previousPage();">Previous Page</button>
  <button id="next-button" class="paging-button btn" onclick="nextPage();">Next Page</button>
  </div>
```

And changed the css using margin spacing in px:

```
#prev-button{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    }

#next-button{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

both buttons have the class `.paging-button`. So both have the same position according to your class:

```
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

Try adding specific position for each button according to it's id and not from a common class.

Comment: Did exactly this http://d.pr/i/BXbi and this is how the buttons turned out http://d.pr/i/IOJv  Any ideas on how to shrink the buttons and bring them together?

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the `position: absolute`, because you have the width on 1060px the buttons will be under each other. You can decrease the width to get the buttons near each other.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wubLL/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a id on both buttons? Use it to style it

This code will position the buttons in the same place because they do have same classes

```
.paging-button {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    color:#fff;
    height:25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    width: 1060px;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would sugest removing the `position: absolute`. then set the `width: auto` for both buttons. next put a `float: left` on the first button and a `float: right` on the second button. I don't guarantee this will work...

Comment: I did your changes: http://d.pr/i/KHps

Shouldn't position be absolute so I can get the buttons ontop of the image?

Comment: you could also give them a `margin-top` with minus :)

Comment: unless the image is a background. if the image is a background to a block element (e.g `<div>` ) you can move the buttons insinde that element. but if it is an `<img>` element than the solution would be a negative `margin-top`